# Behat step definition to verify whether the radio button is checked

Tags: php, bdd, behat, gherkin, mink

I want to write a step definition verify whether a radio button is checked.
Each radio button has an associated label:- 'Yes' or 'No'

The name of the radio buttons inside the input tags is same for the labels associated with a particular radio button

HTML Structure:

```
<label>
    <input type= "radio" name="subscribe_list" value="1" 
    checked="checked">
    :: before
    </input>
    "Yes"
</label>
<label>
    <input type= "radio" name="subscribe_list" value="1" 
    checked="checked">
    </input>
    "No"
<label>
```

Ex: Subscribe to list:   Yes
                         No

There are multiple radio buttons like the above example each with a 'Yes' or 'No' label

I want to write a function which checks whether a 'Yes' or 'No' is checked for a particular radio button name. How should I implement this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the existing steps from Behat, or you can implement your own.

Existing step:

`the "my_checkbox_identifier" checkbox should be checked`

This will work if you are able to identify the checkbox(input) using `field id|name|label|value`.

For implementing a custom step that works with selectors you need to first find the element via existing find method and use `isChecked()` on the returned node, and after use an exception/assert to fail the step if needed.